# How to extract out lines with a pattern and put them in the end of the file

Tags: vim

Suppose I have the following text.

```
a test1
b test2
a test3
b test4
```

what is the command to use to extract out the lines that start with the letter a and put them in the end of the file like this?

```
b test2
b test4

a test1
a test3
```

when I used :g/^a/d and p, the only last match is pasted:

```
b test2
b test4

a test3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only seeing `a test3` at the end, because `:d` sets (not appends) the default register.  Since `:g` executes the given command once per line that matches the pattern, only the last line is in the default register when you paste.

The canonical way to do this would be to use the `:move` (abbreviated as `:m`) command -- `:g/^a/m $`.  For every line that matches `^a`, move it just past the last line (`$`).

A slight modification to your initial approach would be to have `:d` append to a register, and then paste that register afterward.

```
:let @a=''  " Clear register a
:g/^a/d A   " For every line that matches ^a, delete it
            " and append the contents to register a
:$put a     " Paste the contents of register a after the last line
```

The last part could also be done using the normal mode command `"ap`.

Comment: Thank you! quick question. How does `g/^a/d A` know to put the deleted contents into the register "a? does the capital letter A mean the register "a?

Comment: @Alby: Exactly.  See `:help quote_alpha`